# Why test and UITest and xctest file in Xcode project.

Tags: ios, xcode

Its a very basic thing that in Xcode once we create the application multiple files are created default.

1. projectName.xctest
2. projectNameTests.m
3. projectNameUITests.m
4. projectName.entitlements

Can any one know the perps of these files and how and what can we use them.

Thanks

Comment: these files are used for automated UI testing. you can read about this here : https://www.appcoda.com/automated-ui-test/

Answer (score 0):

These files are related to doing Unit testing the project. Once you will learn unit testing you will understand the basics and purpose of these files.

.xctest file is the file when you use XCtest framework to write a unit test case for your project.

projectNameTests.m - Unit test case which will have your unit test which you will be writing for your business logic.

projectNameUITests.m - This file will be having the unit test cases for UI.

projectName.entitlements - Entitlements confer specific capabilities or security permissions to your iOS or macOS app.

Please always to some basic search to find the answer.

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/Miscellaneous/Reference/EntitlementKeyReference/Chapters/AboutEntitlements.html

https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/04-writing_tests.html